# How to count the positions in a letter sequence with using numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numpy, for-loop

Hi I have 3 sequences like this

```
Dna =  ['ACGTAT' 'AGCTAT' 'CGTCGA']
```

All the 3 sequences are consist of A, C, G , T, 
and each sequence consist of 6 letters
So I want to make a 4,6 numpy matrix with the letters count for each position.

Example answer

```
[[2. 0. 0. 0. 2. 1.] -A
 [0. 2. 1. 0. 1. 0.] -C
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.] -G
 [0. 0. 1. 2. 0. 2.]]-T
```

what i'm trying

```
Dna =  ['ACGTAT' 'AGCTAT' 'CGTCGA']
NT_OPTIONS = 'ACGT'
nt_to_index = {nt: i for i, nt in enumerate(NT_OPTIONS)}
pairs_count = np.zeros((4, 6))

for dna_seq in Dna:
    for i in range(len(dna_seq) - 1):
        pairs_count[nt_to_index[dna_seq[i]], nt_to_index[dna_seq[i + 1]]] += 1

print(pairs_count)
```

but this doesn't give my answer. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following, using a list comprehension - there may be a nice numpy vectorisable approach though.

```
>>> Dna = ['ACGTAT','AGCTAT','CGTCGA']
>>> np.array([[sum(1 if s[i]==c else 0 for s in Dna) for i in range(6)] for c in ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']])
array([[2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized way -

```
In [46]: search_lbl = ['A','G','C','T']

In [47]: (np.array(Dna).view('U1').reshape(len(Dna),-1,1)==search_lbl).sum(0).T
Out[47]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]])
```

To improve performance further, we can work with numbers than strings -

```
In [80]: a = np.array(Dna).view(np.uint8)[::4].reshape(len(Dna),-1)

In [81]: s = np.array(search_lbl).view(np.uint8)[::4]

In [82]: (a[...,None]==s).sum(0).T
Out[82]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]])
```